# Properly Handing Anchors in AngularStrap's ScrollSpy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

How can I properly use AngularStrap's ScrollSpy interface to link to anchors within the current document?

Looking at the [AngularStrap documentation](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) I see that when a link is visited a double hash is actually generated. Such as: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##scrollspy

However, when implementing the functionality myself I do not see this behavior. In my case the anchor tags are attempting to update the location instead of moving to a location within the current document.

My AngularStrap ScrollSpy resides on a sub-page: `my-site.com/#/hig`. With the following definition:

```
<div class="hig-sidebar hidden-print hidden-sm hidden-xs" role="complementary" data-offset-top="-34" bs-affix bs-scrollspy-list>
  <ul class="nav hig-sidenav">
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#overview">
      <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#suboverview"><a href="#suboverview">Subsection</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#accessibility"><a href="#accessibility">Accessibility</a></li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#typography"><a href="#typography">Color and Typography</a></li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#graphics"><a href="#graphics">Icons and Graphics</a></li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#navigation"><a href="#navigation">Navigation Design</a></li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#elements"><a href="#elements">UI Elements</a></li>
    <li bs-scrollspy data-target="#reference"><a href="#reference">Reference</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href ng-click="gotoTop()">Back to top</a>
</div>
```

As I scroll through the document, the ScrollSpy properly highlights the current section. But when I click on a link, for example the Color and Typography link, it updates the URL to: `my-site.com/#typography`.

I've been looking at the AngularStrap code and can't see what I haven't done that it is doing. How can I make sure the anchor link adds to the `#/hig` instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as I have explained here:
https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/573

In Angularjs the anchor links like `<a href="#overview">Overview</a>` do not work when you have $routeProvider for configuring your routing. 
You can fixed this by replacing the anchor links with a controller, as follows:

controller:

```
$scope.scrolltoHref = function (id){
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash(id);
        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
    };
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="scrolltoHref('overview')">Overview</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you talk about "update the location", i think that you may be using the scroll spy within an `ngView` directive. In this case, check out the workaround described at the beginning of this issue:

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/573

This helped me to have a kind of working solution, with minor offsets issues